# Two self sizing view inside one table view cell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, constraints

Good evening! I want to put one table view inside cell of another table view. And inside main table view cell self sized collection view and below should be another self sized table view. But XCode want to add height constraint to collection view above or to table view below. But I need to set "wrap content" to both of them. How to do it? Please help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: For complicated layouts like this, I've found Xcode to be much better behaved when you embed the table view and collection view in a `UIContainerView`. It's not perfect, in that Xcode will sometimes still warn about sizing irregularities, but it's cleaner than what you're seeing.

Comment: @matt true, but if you click on the widget in the Object Library, it's referenced as "Container View UIContainerView". In reality it's just a UIView. Probably just a UI cleanup bit overlooked in the initial implementation.

Comment: @particleman Cool thank you for that clarification!